# Why can't I switch from the ad-hoc network settings to the wifi settings?

Tags: wifi

I followed the instructions from [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/04/22/raspberry-pi-wireless-communication/) link to set up an ad hoc network. I get the following strange behaviour.

If my `/etc/network/interfaces` file is the "wifi - regular" file on boot then everything is great. I can switch between the ad hoc configuration and the wifi one using `ifup` and `ifdown` and copying the settings over. However, if I boot with the adhoc configurations the following strange thing happens:

- I cannot switch to the wifi settings successfully. What happens is that although I do `ifdown wlan0` copy the interface file over and then `ifup wlan0`. The wifi does not connect to any networks. I've connected a monitor to the Pi so that's how I'm checking that.

I'm running a Raspberry Pi B+ and the `uname -a` output is:

> Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7+ #817 PREEMPT armv6l GNU/Linux

Any help much appreciated.

These are my configuration files.

`/etc/network/interfaces-adhoc`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  wireless-channel 1
  wireless-essid RPiwireless
  wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

---

`/etc/network/interfaces-wifi`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface etho0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

---

`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```
ddns-update-style interim;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.150;
}
```

**EDIT**

To switch the settings once logged in I do:

```
sudo cp /etc/network/interface-<DESIRED> /etc/network/interface
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

**EDIT 2**

```
| on boot          | wifi        | Ad hoc      |
|----------------------------------------------|
| DHCP on boot?    | failed      | active      |
| can switch?      | yes         | no          |
| IP on boot       | 10.0.0.114  | 192.168.1.1 |
| after 1 switch   | 192.168.1.1 | 192.168.1.1 |
| after 2 switches | 192.168.1.1 | 192.168.1.1 |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

- DHCP on boot: `sudo service isc-dhcp-server status`
- Whether I can switch between the two interfaces and connect succesfully to the internet.
- What the IP is when I first boot
- What the IP is after 1 switch
- What the IP is after 2 switches

I read the IP from `ifconfig wlan0`. This is a bit strange given the network is in the 10.0.0.XX range.

[1](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/04/22/raspberry-pi-wireless-communication/) Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!

Comment: So you basically say, that if you start with `/etc/network/interfaces` with the content of `/etc/network/interfaces-wifi` then you can switch as many times as you like? But if you boot with `/etc/network/interfaces`  having the content of `/etc/network/interfaces-adhoc`, it fails, right?

Comment: it fails to switch. correct. Thanks for the comments, I corrected the plural. Let me know if you have other suggestions.

Comment: edited the question to show how I would do that

Comment: To confirm: if started "with" `-wifi` you can then switch 10 times?

Comment: that is correct. I've been trying to debug some more and it's related to the static IP address in some way. I'll see if I can post more useful information.

Comment: Although I havent specified a password, the network requires one?

Answer (score 0):

If you boot with your `interfaces-adhoc` which contains `iface eth0 inet dhcp` you effectively disable `dhcpcd`. This would prevent the `interfaces-wifi` from running, because this depends on `dhcpcd`.

You are trying to run 2 incompatible services. It **MAY** be possible to write a script which shuts down all the services not needed and start others, but you are on your own. It is going to be easier to just reboot.

Comment: so is the "right" way to set up a rasbperry pi to serve a website so you can configure it's wifi settings by doing what I've been doing above and then forcing it to restart?

Comment: @evan54 I can't say what is "right", I was pointing out why your approach didn't work, and how I would have done it (indeed I have experimented with an Access Point this way). There are hundreds of ways of configuring networking on Linux.

Comment: thanks for the response. just to make sure I understand. Is the way you would have done it simply rebooting?